# Nonlinear model in r

Tags: r

What is the problem with the following r code as I get error?

```
nonlinear <- function(G,Q,T) {
    Y=G+Q*X^T
}

Model <- nls(nonlinear, start = list(G=0.4467, Q=-0.0020537, T=1), data=sample1)

Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Comment: Can you please give some data, e.g. the result of `dput(head(sample1, 10))`? BTW: your call of `nls()` is wrong. Please give some description what you want to aim.

Comment: In your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264277/nonlinear-modelling-starting-values the call is ok.

Comment: I am trying to make a nonlinear modelling from a huge datasets  and x is the count data and Y is the growth rate of population i.e ( calculated log(Nt+1/Nt)) and I think you are right, nls(), may be wrong, can you give me different options?

Comment: Please put the new information in your question (not in a comment), i.e. edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52221054/edit

Comment: `nonlinear<-function(X,G,Q,T) G+Q*X^T;  Model<-nls(Y ~ nonlinear(X,G,Q,T),start = list(G=0.4467,Q=-0.0020537,T=1), data=sample1)` is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the data from your other question [Nonlinear modelling starting values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264277/nonlinear-modelling-starting-values) and the code from @Roland this works:

```
sample1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"X         Y                  Z
135      -0.171292376      85  
91      0.273954718        54   
171     -0.288513438       107
88       -0.17363066       54
59     -1.770852012        50
1        0                 37
1       0                  32
1       0.301029996        36
2       -0.301029996       39
1       1.041392685        30
11      -0.087150176       42
9        0.577236408       20
34       -0.355387658      28
15        0.329058719      17
32        -0.182930683     24
21        0.196294645      21
33        0.114954516      91
43       -0.042403849      111
39       -0.290034611       88
20       -0.522878746       76
6        -0.301029995       108
3         0.477121254       78
9          0                63
9          0.492915522      51
28       -0.243038048       88
16        -0.028028724      17
15      -0.875061263        29
2       -0.301029996        44
1        0                  52
1        1.531478917        65")

nonlinear<-function(X,G,Q,T) G+Q*X^T
nls(Y ~ nonlinear(X,G,Q,T), start=list(G=-0.4, Q=0.2, T=-1), data=sample1)
```

**Depending from the data I had to change the starting values!**

Comment: Thanks, Jogo and Roland! But, it gives me the following error: Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model . I am using large datasets and I don't care whether it gives me large missing values but it couldn't give me any result.

Comment: @Stackuser How can I reproduce the error without any data? The code in the answer (as it is) works fine.